# Windows 10 Performance monitor counter table too small, sometimes freezes

Tags: windows-10, performance-monitor

The Performance monitor on Windows 10 has the table listing the counters squished to one line height. See screenshot below. I have two counters, but the table shows one (to see the other I must scroll the table). If I add more counters, the table grows, but to size minus one, IOW in case of 5 counters, it shows 4 and the remaining is seen when scrolling the table content.

So the table is one item too short.

I tried on another Windows 10 PC and there the table grows to show all items.

Resizing the windows does not make any difference. Also I see no way to manually resize the table.

[image]

PS: another issue is that sometimes the update stops. It just stays showing the same data. The vertical red line also stops moving. All the GUI works, it just does not update the counter values. Probably not related to the above issue, but as both happened on the same day, I post them together.

PPS: Screenshot of graph Properties, as requested in comment:

[image]

Comment: Right-click the graph and go to Properties, then add a screenshot from each of the 5 tabs to your question, please.

Comment: @spikey_richie  added

Comment: Thanks. I can't replicate your issue with the settings you have. What's the screen resolution? Do you have any Scaling options set in the OS?

Comment: @spikey_richie 2560x1440 + 1920x180 , scaling set to 100% on both

Comment: "1920x180" are you using this tool at that resolution? 180 pixels isn't much real estate to show the graph and axis rows.

Comment: @spikey_richie no, it is on the bigger screen (also I don't see why moving from one to ther should change the layout; the other PC I tested has 1920x1080 and there it works without this issue)